# $\mu,\nu$ are Borel pr. measures s.t. $|\int fd\nu-\int fd\mu|<\epsilon$ for some Lipschitz $f$ then the inequality holds for some bounded $g\in C(X)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $\mu,\nu$ be two Borel probability measures over $X$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be fixed and suppose that

$$\left|\int_X fd\nu - \int_Xfd\mu\right| < \epsilon$$

for some **non-zero** Lipschitz function $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$. Does there then exists a bounded **non-zero** continuous function $g:X\to\mathbb{R}$ that

$$\left|\int_X gd\nu - \int_Xgd\mu\right| < \epsilon$$

A book I am reading says essentially that yes, because Lipschitz functions are continuous. My initial idea was to cut $f$ with some thresholds, e.g. $g(x) = \chi_{\{t_1\leq f(x)\leq t_2\}}(x)f(x) + \chi_{\{f(x) < t_1\}}(x)t_1 + \chi_{\{f(x) > t_2\}}(x)t_2$, but it is all but clear to me how I can choose $t_1,t_2$ such that

$$\left|\int_X gd\nu - \int_Xgd\mu\right| < \epsilon$$

holds.

Comment: You can always choose these functions to be the zero function. I guess you want to exclude this somehow? Maybe restrict to positive functions?

Comment: @jakobdt Ah, good catch! Yeah, I am interested in knowing whether if $f$ is a non-zero Lipschitz function, can we find a non-zero bounded continuous function $g$ possibly depending on $f$.

Comment: If you find a bounded and continuous function $h$ which is integrable w.r.t. both $\mu$ and $\nu$ then you can scale it to obtain $g$ with $\int_X\lvert g\rvert\,\mathrm{d}\mu,\int_X\lvert g\rvert\,\mathrm{d}\nu<\epsilon/2$. To construct $h$ I'm guessing that you can use the Lipschitz continuity of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both $f$ and $g$ exist *always*. Choose the constant function $g \equiv 1$, which is continuous. Since $\mu$ and $\nu$ are probability measures, both integrals give the value $1$ and their difference is zero, which is smaller than any $\varepsilon >0$.